# Django URL conf conf redirecting to wrong view

Tags: python, django, url

Writing an app for college students -- shows a list of departments, you click on one, then it shows you the classes in that department, click on one, and then shows the professors teaching that class.

Having problems with the URL conf -- my app keeps redirecting me to the wrong view.

So I've got 3 models

```
class Department(models.Model):
    subject         = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
    pub_date        = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.subject

class Course(models.Model):
    department      = models.ForeignKey(Department)
    course_number   = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    course_name     = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank = True, null = True)
    c_pub_date      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.course_number

class Professor(models.Model):
    course          = models.ForeignKey(Course)
    prof_name       = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    p_pub_date      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.prof_name
```

Then my app URL conf goes to the views, courses and professors, depending on the URL

```
urlpatterns = patterns('qanda.views',
    url(r'^$', 'index'),
    url(r'(?P<department_id>\d+)/$', 'courses'),
    url(r'(?P<department_id>\d+)/(?P<course_id>\d+)/$', 'professors'),
)
```

So when I go to the url mysite.com, it lists all the departments in the database. Then clicking on a single department (ie Math), it will take me to the course view at mysite.com/1, which shows me all of the courses in that department. Then clicking on a course should take me to the professors view mysite.com/1/1, which shows me all the professors teaching that class.

However, when I get to the course view and click on a course to get to professors view, even though the URL displays mysite.com/1/2, it actually redirects me back to mysite.com/2, taking the course_id (in this case, 2) and the mistaking it for the departmment_id, and redirecting me to the courses view.

For example, Math 101 course_id = 1. Math 102 course_id = 2. For Math 101, there are 2 professors. Professor A professor_id = 1, Professor B professor_id = 2.

So when clicking on Math 101, URL will be mysite.com/1. When clicking on Professor B after, URL will be mysite.com/1/2. however, right now when clicking on professor B, URl displays mysite.com/1/2, but takes me to mysite.com/2.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Can you give code of the views and not of the models?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that your regex is too vague.. you're missing the `^` so your first URL is matching before your second one gets a chance to.

`(\d+)/$` would match `/3/, foo/3/, foo/bar/baz/3`

It has nothing to do with a trailing slash. That's a standard django URL pattern. `/$`

```
url(r'^$', 'index'),
url(r'(?P<department_id>\d+)/$', 'courses'),
#   ^^^ needs ^
url(r'(?P<department_id>\d+)/(?P<course_id>\d+)/$', 'professors'),
```

Comment: doh. can't believe I missed it. Thanks!

Comment: actually the trailing slash may be important, but django may be tolerant of your mistake, depending on your setup (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash)

Comment: @simon, no - if `APPEND_SLASH` was turned off and the slash became relevant, you'd get a 404, not the other view.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you have two problems – the missing caret and, the trailing slash.  try this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('qanda.views',
    url(r'^$', 'index'),
    url(r'^(?P<department_id>\d+)/?$', 'courses'),
    url(r'^(?P<department_id>\d+)/(?P<course_id>\d+)/?$', 'professors'),
)
```

Comment: still not working. I have it set up deparment > course > professor. right now it's listing department-- clicking on a department takes me to a list of courses in that department. However, clicking on a course just takes me to another department with the same id as the course.

Comment: pardon me, the regexs weren't quite right -- I've edited my answer, can you try again?